# How Write LINQ join mutiple conditions

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, conditional-statements

I have formed the following LINQ query, but .. . . .

if you have a third join ...in this case condional... how write this ?

example :

```
 var query = from trip in db.Trips
from driver in db.Drivers
condition1 ?  join X in other_table : join Y in other_table2 
where trip.DriverId == driver.DriverId ||
      trip.CoDriverId == driver.DriverId
select new { driver.DriverId, trip.TripId };
```

Comment: did you consider constructing 2 different queries based on condition, as oppose to trying to dynamically assembling it

Comment: I recommend create an appropriate view at database level and query it via LINQ.

Comment: you can do left join on all other tables and then operate with them

Answer (score 2):

If the type of `other_table` and `other_table2` where the same, then the easiest way to do this would be:

```
IQueryable<SomeType> joinTable = condition1 ? other_table : other_table2;
```

And then use `join j in joinTable` as part of your query.

Otherwise, if you are only using the join to restrict a where condition, rather than to affect the fields, you could first write `query` to ignore that and then add something like:

```
if(condition1)
   query = query.Where(q => other_table.Where(o => foo==bar).Select(o => o.DriverId).Contains(q.DriverId));
else
   query = query.Where(q => other_table.Select(o => o.DriverId).Contains(q.DriverId));
```

Here the restriction of `foo==bar` is to show that we can add quite a bit of detail to these further `Where` clauses if necessary. The main thing is that `Where` doesn't change the type of the result; `query` is `IQueryable<T>` for some `T`, and remains so after the `Where` so we can assign that query back to `query`.

If the join is to add values then:

```
var newQuery = condition1
  ? query.Join(other_table, q=>DriverId, ot => ot.DriverId, (q, ot) => new {q.DriverID, q.TripId, ot.OtherField}
  : query.Join(other_table2, q=>DriverId, ot => ot.DriverId, (q, ot) => new {q.DriverId, q.TripId, OtherField = ot.YetAnotherField};
```

Note that `other_table.OtherField` and `ot.YetAnotherField` must be of the same type. This depends on the compiler creating any anonymous classes with the same name, order and type of fields as the same class, so `newQuery`'s type can be deduced (and is the same for each branch). If they are not the same type then you need to either cast one to the type of the other, or else do something like:

```
var newQuery = condition1
  ? query.Join(other_table, q=>DriverId, ot => ot.DriverId, (q, ot) => new {q.DriverID, q.TripId, ot.OtherField, YetAnotherField = (string)null}
  : query.Join(other_table2, q=>DriverId, ot => ot.DriverId, (q, ot) => new {q.DriverId, q.TripId, OtherField = -1, ot.YetAnotherField};
```

In this last example, `OtherField` is an integer which is set to `-1` if `condition1` was true, while `YetAnotherField` is a string which is set to `null` if `condition1` was false.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the core question, so:

```
 var query = from trip in db.Trips
             from driver in (condition1 ? cdb.Drivers1 : cdb.Drivers2)
             where trip.DriverId == driver.DriverId ||
             trip.CoDriverId == driver.DriverId
             select new { driver.DriverId, trip.TripId };
```

Comment: It'll work if the two sources are of the same type, not otherwise

Comment: It's true (it also seems that he uses TypedDataSet then certainly it is different types). Your answer is correct. Another suggestion: Sometimes you should concatenate the tables at the database level (in DataAdapter), with the UNION.